# PHP can't echo for each array

Tags: php, list, multidimensional-array, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to echo out an array using for each but it's not displaying any values.  The only values i can echo out is within a second for each.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

What i am trying to echo is the price, item, description etc but i am getting nothing.

If you need to see the output of the array it's here http://operationbraveheart.org.uk/jcart/testshop.php

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
    $superitem[$row['itemid']][] = $row;
}
foreach($superitem AS $subitem) {
    list($prodid,$item,$size,$description,$price) = $subitem[0];

    if ($count % NUMCOLS == 0) echo "<tr>";  # new row
    echo '<td>'; 
    var_dump($subitem);
    //Your normal code up until the select box...
    echo '<form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="'.$_SESSION['jcartToken'].'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="'.$subitem['prodid'].'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="'.$subitem['price'].'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="http://yahoo.com" />';

    if(count($subitem) > 1) {

        echo '<li><select name="my-item-name" id="foo">';
        foreach($subitem AS $subsubitem) {
            echo "<option value='".$subsubitem['size']."'>".$subsubitem['size']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="'.$subitem['item'].'" />'; 
    }
    echo'<li>Price: $<span class="price">'.$subitem['price'].'</span></li>
                <li>
                    <label>Qty: <input type="text" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" /></label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="add to cart" class="button" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>';

    echo '</td>';
    $count++;
    $counter++;

    if ($count % NUMCOLS == 0) echo "</tr>\n";  # end row
}
```

Comment: What does `$subitem` contain?

Comment: An array of products from database.  I'll add the var_dump again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current it looks like $subitem contains an array of length 1 where the first index is a row. Change...

```
$superitem[$row['itemid']][] = $row;
```

should be...

```
$superitem[$row['itemid']] = $row;
```

and...

```
list($prodid,$item,$size,$description,$price) = $subitem[0];
```

should be...

```
list($prodid,$item,$size,$description,$price) = $subitem;
```

Comment: I changed it but now i've got drop down lists for every product.  Can you please look at my page again and see what's happening?

Comment: Can you explain a bit further about how you're wanting the final page to look?

Comment: Have a look at my page i linked to.  I've temporarily undone the changes you suggested even tho they give me prices etc, just so you can see how i want it to look.  You will see there is one drop down list and the rest are normal forms.